# How to limit upload speed in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, upload, rate-limits

I've got an application ([aws-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli)) that takes over all the bandwidth when uploading, which means in the meantime no other application can access the internet.

So I'm wondering is it possible to limit the upload speed of an application or even the whole connection (whatever is simpler)? Like I would like to set it so that upload is never faster than 50KB/s. Any way to do this in Windows 10?

Comment: You would have to use third-party software to accomplish this task.

Comment: You could try setting the priority of the application to Below Normal or lower using SysInternals' Process Explorer or Windows Task Manager. This will have the side effect of making the application less responsive to input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, I've ended up using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) which has built-in rate limiting with the `--limit-rate` option.

None of the other tools mentioned in this page seemed to work for this case, perhaps because aws-cli was run from WSL.

Comment: To be fair you made absolutely no reference to WSL in the body of your question l.  You also asked the question before it was considered a stable feature. 1709 wasn’t released until Oct 2017 but you made no reference to the version of Windows you had installed either

Answer (score 2):

Try NetLimiter (http://www.netlimiter.com/).

With NetLimiter, you can see your running programs and apply a DL/UL limit to any of them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you may need to use dedicated  third-party softwares (with specialised bandwidth filtering service). One that'd come to mind is [Netbalancer](https://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/)

> NetBalancer is an internet traffic control and monitoring tool, with
> loads of features to:
>
> - Set for any process a **download and/or upload network priority or limit.**
> - Manage priorities and limits for each network adapter separately Define detailed network traffic rules
> - Group local network computers and balance their traffic synchronised
> - Set global traffic limits.

In a nutshell, Netlancer allows one to control every aspect of the network traffic on their PC with deep packet inspection (DPI), priorities and time based rules.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the above mentioned software, but I personally use it, hence shared this info.

Comment: @this_lau Please don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you.