# How can I configure Windows so that it prioritizes download over upload?

Tags: windows, internet

When I use Windows, uploads are typically low priority (e.g., background online disk backup) while download are typically high priority (e.g., loading my emails). How can I configure Windows so that it prioritizes download over upload? I currently use Windows 10 and 11.

Answer (score 2):

Windows itself might not be easy to configure to set upload and download speed limits, but many third-party tools *can* do so, such as [Free Download Manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) and [qBittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/), shown below.

[image: Set Upload and Download Limits]

Note that some of these tools can be integrated into web browsers and other applications, so using them is transparent; i.e., when you start a file transfer of greater size than a limit you set, the third-party application performs the actual download automatically. Some allow specifying speed limit by time of day, file type, etc.

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1260278/how-to-limit-upload-speed-in-windows-10) for a similar, but not identical, question.

**N.B.** Any third-party software, and particularly downloading tools, should be checked for malware before use, e.g. at [VirusTotal](https://so,%20such%20as%20%5BFree%20Download%20Manager%5D%5B2%5D%20and%20%5BqBittorrent%5D%5B3%5D,%20shown%20below.).